# Empty functions in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently reading a "tutorial" (it's really just the code) about how to make a calendar in ReactJS and it contains a lot of empty functions. Below you can find the code:

```
var Calendar = React.createClass({
    calc: function (year, month) {},
    componentWillMount: function () {},
    componentDidMount: function () {},
    componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {},
    getPrev: function () {},
    getNext: function () {},
    selectDate: function (year, month, date, element) {},
    render: function () {
        return (
           //some code
        );
    }
});

var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function () {}
});
```

(Source: https://zinoui.com/blog/react-calendar-component)

What do the empty functions indicate? How can they have any purpose if they don't do anything and why would you include them anyway? Or is the code just incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you provided (https://zinoui.com/blog/react-calendar-component) the author probably just forgot to fill those functions in,

In [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/ufew4pck/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ufew4pck) they are not empty - I copy-paste the code:

```
/**
 * React Calendar Component v0.1.1
 *
 * Copyright 2016, Dimitar Ivanov
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */
var Calendar = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Calendar',
    calc: function (year, month) {
        if (this.state.selectedElement) {
            if (this.state.selectedMonth != month || this.state.selectedYear != year) {
                this.state.selectedElement.classList.remove('r-selected');
            } else {
                this.state.selectedElement.classList.add('r-selected');
            }
        }
        return {
            firstOfMonth: new Date(year, month, 1),
            daysInMonth: new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate()
        };
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState(this.calc.call(null, this.state.year, this.state.month));
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {},
    componentDidUpdate: function (prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.onSelect && prevState.selectedDt != this.state.selectedDt) {
            this.props.onSelect.call(this.getDOMNode(), this.state);
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        var date = new Date();
        return {
            year: date.getFullYear(),
            month: date.getMonth(),
            selectedYear: date.getFullYear(),
            selectedMonth: date.getMonth(),
            selectedDate: date.getDate(),
            selectedDt: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()),
            startDay: 1,
            weekNumbers: false,
            minDate: this.props.minDate ? this.props.minDate : null,
            disablePast: this.props.disablePast ? this.props.disablePast : false,
            dayNames: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
            monthNames: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            monthNamesFull: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            firstOfMonth: null,
            daysInMonth: null
        };
    },
    getPrev: function () {
        var state = {};
        if (this.state.month > 0) {
            state.month = this.state.month - 1;
            state.year = this.state.year;
        } else {
            state.month = 11;
            state.year = this.state.year - 1;
        }
        Object.assign(state, this.calc.call(null, state.year, state.month));
        this.setState(state);
    },
    getNext: function () {
        var state = {};
        if (this.state.month < 11) {
            state.month = this.state.month + 1;
            state.year = this.state.year;
        } else {
            state.month = 0;
            state.year = this.state.year + 1;
        }
        Object.assign(state, this.calc.call(null, state.year, state.month));
        this.setState(state);
    },
    selectDate: function (year, month, date, element) {
        if (this.state.selectedElement) {
            this.state.selectedElement.classList.remove('r-selected');
        }
        element.target.classList.add('r-selected');
        this.setState({
            selectedYear: year,
            selectedMonth: month,
            selectedDate: date,
            selectedDt: new Date(year, month, date),
            selectedElement: element.target
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            { className: 'r-calendar' },
            React.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'r-inner' },
                React.createElement(Header, { monthNames: this.state.monthNamesFull, month: this.state.month, year: this.state.year, onPrev: this.getPrev, onNext: this.getNext }),
                React.createElement(WeekDays, { dayNames: this.state.dayNames, startDay: this.state.startDay, weekNumbers: this.state.weekNumbers }),
                React.createElement(MonthDates, { month: this.state.month, year: this.state.year, daysInMonth: this.state.daysInMonth, firstOfMonth: this.state.firstOfMonth, startDay: this.state.startDay, onSelect: this.selectDate, weekNumbers: this.state.weekNumbers, disablePast: this.state.disablePast, minDate: this.state.minDate })
            )
        );
    }
});

var Header = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Header',

    render: function () {
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            { className: 'r-row r-head' },
            React.createElement('div', { className: 'r-cell r-prev', onClick: this.props.onPrev.bind(this), role: 'button', tabIndex: '0' }),
            React.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'r-cell r-title' },
                this.props.monthNames[this.props.month],
                ' ',
                this.props.year
            ),
            React.createElement('div', { className: 'r-cell r-next', onClick: this.props.onNext.bind(this), role: 'button', tabIndex: '0' })
        );
    }
});

var WeekDays = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'WeekDays',

    render: function () {
        var that = this,
            haystack = Array.apply(null, { length: 7 }).map(Number.call, Number);
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            { className: 'r-row r-weekdays' },
            (() => {
                if (that.props.weekNumbers) {
                    return React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'r-cell r-weeknum' },
                        'wn'
                    );
                }
            })(),
            haystack.map(function (item, i) {
                return React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'r-cell' },
                    that.props.dayNames[(that.props.startDay + i) % 7]
                );
            })
        );
    }
});

var MonthDates = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'MonthDates',

    statics: {
        year: new Date().getFullYear(),
        month: new Date().getMonth(),
        date: new Date().getDate(),
        today: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate())
    },
    render: function () {
        var haystack,
            day,
            d,
            current,
            onClick,
            isDate,
            className,
            weekStack = Array.apply(null, { length: 7 }).map(Number.call, Number),
            that = this,
            startDay = this.props.firstOfMonth.getUTCDay(),
            first = this.props.firstOfMonth.getDay(),
            janOne = new Date(that.props.year, 0, 1),
            rows = 5;

        if (startDay == 5 && this.props.daysInMonth == 31 || startDay == 6 && this.props.daysInMonth > 29) {
            rows = 6;
        }

        className = rows === 6 ? 'r-dates' : 'r-dates r-fix';
        haystack = Array.apply(null, { length: rows }).map(Number.call, Number);
        day = this.props.startDay + 1 - first;
        while (day > 1) {
            day -= 7;
        }
        day -= 1;
        return React.createElement(
            'div',
            { className: className },
            haystack.map(function (item, i) {
                d = day + i * 7;
                return React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'r-row' },
                    (() => {
                        if (that.props.weekNumbers) {
                            var wn = Math.ceil(((new Date(that.props.year, that.props.month, d) - janOne) / 86400000 + janOne.getDay() + 1) / 7);
                            return React.createElement(
                                'div',
                                { className: 'r-cell r-weeknum' },
                                wn
                            );
                        }
                    })(),
                    weekStack.map(function (item, i) {
                        d += 1;
                        isDate = d > 0 && d <= that.props.daysInMonth;

                        if (isDate) {
                            current = new Date(that.props.year, that.props.month, d);
                            className = current != that.constructor.today ? 'r-cell r-date' : 'r-cell r-date r-today';
                            if (that.props.disablePast && current < that.constructor.today) {
                                className += ' r-past';
                            } else if (that.props.minDate !== null && current < that.props.minDate) {
                                className += ' r-past';
                            }

                            if (/r-past/.test(className)) {
                                return React.createElement(
                                    'div',
                                    { className: className, role: 'button', tabIndex: '0' },
                                    d
                                );
                            }

                            return React.createElement(
                                'div',
                                { className: className, role: 'button', tabIndex: '0', onClick: that.props.onSelect.bind(that, that.props.year, that.props.month, d) },
                                d
                            );
                        }

                        return React.createElement('div', { className: 'r-cell' });
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Calendar, {
    //onSelect: function (state) {
    //console.log(this, state);
    //},
    //disablePast: true,
    //minDate: new Date(2016, 2, 28)
}), document.getElementById("calendar"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the exact intention of the author of the blog post you're referring to, but, I can give you a couple of hints about Methods on React components.

1. React now supports ES6 classes and pure functions to create components. Basically `React.createClass` is deprecated, however using it is not suggested.
2. React components, if written in ES6 classical way, carry some built-in lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc. They can also have custom methods on their instances. As you define those custom methods(functions), You probably wanna use them in component's `render` method to render some crazy stuff into DOM. This way you'll end up calling the function in your render method, and if you don't pass those methods as props to your component when used, it will throw error and JS will complain.
   Defining empty functions as default props can help you bypass these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the empty functions in the code you posted are built in functions on React components. Some of them aren't, so I reckon that the author left them blank for some other reason - maybe just defining the signature of the component, etc.

React components have a 'lifecycle' - essentially, these functions dictate what the component will do at certain, well-defined points during application use. You can read more about the individual functions and the overall lifecycle [here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

For example, `componentDidMount` will fire off the  *first*  time your component comes to life - if you want to perform some action at that point in time, you would put that logic here. I like to think of this as a component's version of something like `document.onload`.

There are also functions that help you  *control*  the actual lifecycle - `shouldComponentUpdate`, for example, lets you tell your component  *when*  to re-render itself. If you decide that you don't want a to fire off a new render when your state/props change to `foo`, then you'd put that logic here.

These functions offer a lot of flexibility when writing React components. The default behavior works fine in many cases, but as an app grows and components get more complicated, they might need that slight bit of customization.

You can read more about what lifecycle functions are available to you and how to use them in the docs, but hopefully this has given you an idea of why they're there.